# Interface configuration - Internet not working

Tags: server, internet, interface

I just tried to configure eth0 interface on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 Lts.

I want to set up static ip, therefore I put the following lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
## To configure a dynamic IP address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

## Or configure a static IP
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.111
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.1.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

I can perfectly ping my router with this configuration. I also can connect to the server from my laptop via ssh. But internet is not working:

```
ping google.de
ping: unknown host google.de
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Jap, definitely duplicate, shall I remove my post?

Comment: No, just leave it. It'll be closed as a duplicate and might serve others bumping into your question with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a nameserver for the static configuration.

Append a stanza

```
 dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

or whatever DNS you like to use. Specify multiple DNS server as a space-separated list.

Bring the interface down and up to trigger `resolvconf`

```
 sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```